# How to install Craft on live server parallel to existing CMS?

Tags: migration

I'm in the process of migrating a large, complex site to Craft.

I've reached the stage where I like to install Craft in parallel to my existing CMS with the intention of allowing users to help me check the content is migrated correctly.

It's also with a view to keep parts of the existing site in the current CMS and migrate them later.

Do you have advice on how to best do this? How would I redirect requests for different parts of the site to the correct CMS?

Answer (score 1):

Is the existing CMS live?
Often depends on your whole development process.
Quick thoughts would be to use a subdomain of live site.,e eg 'staging.mysite.com'

For managing redirects the answer is it depends.
Typically htaccess 301 redirects
Redirect 301 /my old url  https://www.mynewurl.com/my old url

You can replace the latter domain name with subdomain name eg as above 'staging' and then switch to real domain when live.

Depending upon Craft version you could use Retour for Craft2 or check the plugin directory for redirect management solutions.

Or if the original url structure is solid then you can always make craft match in section  settings :)

Comment: [Retour](https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-retour) is out for Craft 3 as well.

Comment: Yes, existing CMS is live. URLs remain mostly the same, my question was with regards to sorting out production (after staging has ended) when the two different CMSs will serve the site.

Comment: Sounds like a tautology - how do I keep bits of the old cms live but also have the sites domain point to my new craftcms. You can't really. You might be able to alias some content but it all sounds a bit messy. Simplest solution must be a subdomain solution?